# Не распознает файл при импорте (Python)

Tags: python, импорт

Имеются два файла `lesson37.py` и `classes.py`. Расположены в одной папке.
Пытаюсь импортировать в `lesson37.py` все из файла `classes.py` (там есть несколько классов).
Однако, почему-то при вводе кода для импорта не распознается файл `classes.py`.

**В чем может быть проблема?**

P.S. Python версии 3.8, Pycharm 2020.
До обновления PyCharm импорт работал... Может с настройками что-то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй сделать так:

from папка_где_всё_наодится.имя_файла_который_нужен import *

```
from folder.classes import *
```

Comment: Ваш способ работает, спасибо!

Comment: Почему тогда Питон не находил файл без указания папки? 
Ведь при импорте в первую очередь Питон ищет файл в той же папке, где расположен редактируемый файл. Я выводил список поиска путей и там была эта папка. Или я ошибаюсь?
Возможно потому, что оба эти файла находятся не в самой папке Проекта, а в ее подпапке

Comment: Не очень понял, но ещё раз объясню: Если хочешь импортировать один файл в другой и они находятся у тебя в одной папке, то можно сделать так (folder1 - там два файла file1, file2)        from .file1 import *. Если файла находятся не в одной папке, то нужно действовать, как я написал в ответе. Надеюсь, что помог.